# jump to next by group when condition is met

Tags: sas

I have a file documenting changes in marital status - ID, type of change (marriage, divorce, being widowed) and year (and month) of change. I want to calculate each person's marital status (married, divorced, widow(er), never been married) for any given year. Since a person can go through many changes and my file is around 20 million rows I'd like to skip to the next person when I find the answer and not continue through all of that person's other records.

I thought to sort by ID and descending date of change and then set by ID. For each ID, if the year I'm interested in is greater than (or equal to) the year of change then calculate marital status and output the ID and marital status. If not, continue to the next record until the condition is met. If no record meets the condition then marital status=never been married.

```
data a;
length type_change $10;
input ID type_change yr_change mnth_change;
cards;
1 marriage 2006 9
1 divorce 2010 5
10 marriage 2005 2
10 divorce 2012 10
10 marriage 2016 8
23 marriage 2017 6
35 marriage 2002 7
35 widow 2013 12
;
run;
```

For 2015 I'd like to get:
- ID  marital_status
- 1   divorced
- 10  divorced
- 23  never been married
- 35  widowed

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the list of all people, that could have been married?

Comment: I have a list of all people. Here I'm focusing on those married at least one since the never been married are easy to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* do this sort only once and save sorted */

proc sort data = have out = sorted;
  by id yr_change;
run;

proc sort data = have (keep =id) out = ids nodupkey; 
  by id;
run;

data step1;
  set sorted;
  where yr_change <= &y;
  by id;
  if last.id;
run;

data want;
  merge step1 (in =a) ids (in =b);
  by id;
  if b and not a then status = "never married";
  else status = type_change;
run;
```

Comment: On the data , that was sampled and your code, I've get : 1-divorce
10-divorce
35-widow. There is no 23 id

Comment: Removed where yr_change <= &y; might be more computationally more expensive now. But if you can sort once and save the dataset, then should be fine

Comment: Remove space in column name "type _change"

Comment: That gives me 'never married' for ID=1 instead of divorced.

Comment: Was just editing to change from < to >. Sorry more edits to be done

Comment: Got it. But now ID=10 gets 'never married' when they should get divorced. Sometimes the answer isn't in the first observation so "if first.id" doesn't always work.

Comment: Apologies, but network got a bit jittery and my edits were getting saved while editing. Try now please

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for giving me a solution and a different way of looking at the problem. Off to try on a much bigger dataset.

Comment: One additional efficiency you can gain is by using a view for step1. i.e. change `data step1` to `data step1 / view = step1`, This can avoid some IO if the output for step1 is relatively large.

Answer (score 1):

If by skip you mean not reading them then you cannot "skip" observations.  But you can ignore them by using IF statement (or other conditional logic).

Using RETAIN and BY group processing should get you answer.

```
%let year=2015;

data want ;
  set a ;
  by id yr_change mnth_change ;
  length status $20;
  retain status ;
  if first.id then status='never been married ';
  if yr_change <= &year then status=type_change ;
  if last.id;
  keep id status;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    ID    status

 1      1    divorce
 2     10    divorce
 3     23    never been married
 4     35    widow
```

If you have access to a master list of ID's you could convert to using a WHERE statement which MIGHT reduce the I/O needed to process all of the records.  For example merge the list of ID's with a subset of the marital status change records.

```
data want;
  merge id_list a(in=in2 where=(yr_change <= &year));
  by id;
  length status $20;
  retain status ;
  if first.id then status='never been married ';
  if in2 then status=type_change ;
  if last.id;
  keep id status;
run;
```

Comment: I believe he refers to skipping as the case where you can actually use where instead of if to avoid IO into PDVs which is more efficient, The proposed solution processes all 20M records which I believe the user wants to avoid

Comment: Note that WHERE would only provide significant performance improvement if source was some external database where filtering the observations would allow less data transfer from the database to SAS.  But that would risk loosing ability to identify subjects like ID=23.  So another source for the list of ID's would need to be provided.

Comment: I will differ with you on this. Perhaps for  a narrow / relatively small dataset such as this one, that is true. We have done benchmarks on datasets in disk with about 100 billion records, each with 200 - 300 attributes where the improvement in using which over if was very significant.

Comment: There are certainly situations where it might matter. Having access to an index that can be used to reduce number of blocks of I/O read from disk. The relative speed of disk I/O versus memory/CPU speed. Having extremely wide observations will require more memory to memory transfers when using IF statement.

Comment: Thanks guys. I do prefer to not have to process all 20M records.

Comment: How many records are going to be able to eliminate? Do you have people with hundreds of marital status changes?

Answer (score 1):

A DOW loop will let you compute a result over a group.  An implicit output will save the result computed for the group.  Because the result is dependent on your year of interest, you will want to track that also in any created data sets.

```
%let YEAR_CUTOFF = 2015;

data want (keep=id status year_cutoff);

  attrib
    id length = 8
    status length=$20 label="Status at year end &YEAR_CUTOFF"
    year_cutoff length = 8
  ;

  retain year_cutoff &YEAR_CUTOFF;

  status = 'never been married';

  do until (last.ID);                                    /* The DOW loop */
    set have (rename=status=status_of_interest);
    by id;
    if year <= &YEAR_CUTOFF then status = status_of_interest;
  end;

  /* No explicit OUTPUT in the step, so,
   * an implicit OUTPUT occurs here at the bottom of the step
   */
run;
```

Comment: In the line "set have (rename=status=status_of_interest);" does status refer to type_change? If it does then ID 1,10 are married instead of divorced.

Comment: Yes, `status` is `type_change`.  I probably coded it as so as an artifact of reading the @Tom answer.  Your `yr_change` is simply `year` in my code -- That's is why you're seeing what you see, running copy/paste has dangers alleviated by understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Then use retain statement.

Extract all IDs:

```
proc sort data=a out=ids(keep= id) nodupkey ;
by id;
run;
```

Generate *all* years that you need to all IDs

```
data years;
set ids;
    must_be_date=2000;

    do i = 1 to 20;
        must_be_date+1;
        output;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

Join by condition:

```
proc sql;
    create table res as 
        select * 
            from years left join a on years.must_be_date = a.yr_change and a.id = years.id
    ;
run;

proc sort ;
by id must_be_date;
run;
```

Use retain:

```
data res;
retain temp "never been married";
set res;
by id must_be_date;
if first.id then temp="never been married";
if type_change="" then type_change = temp;
else temp=type_change;
run;
```

to check :

```
data res_2015;
set res;
where must_be_date=2015;
run;
```

Result table:

```
+--------------------+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|        temp        | ID | must_be_date | type_change | yr_change | mnth_change |
+--------------------+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| divorce            |  1 |         2015 | divorce     |         . |           . |
| divorce            | 10 |         2015 | divorce     |         . |           . |
| never been married | 23 |         2015 | never been  |         . |           . |
| widow              | 35 |         2015 | widow       |         . |           . |
+--------------------+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: That works but would give me a huge table to save and work with. I have 13 million people and years going back to ~1900.